# How do I fetch the record from the correct index of array while aggregation on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

**Problem Statement**

I have an ElasticSearch index that stores the Name of cities and their Ids. It looks like this:

```js
{
  "usr" : "plore113"
  "cityName": "New York",
  "cityId": "150p7"
},
{
  "usr" : "plore114"
  "cityName": "Delhi",
  "cityId": "171x9"
}
```

I'm running an aggregation on this, where I get all the city names bucketed and I also get their Ids. I do it through this:

```js
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "cName": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cityName.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cId": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "cityId.keyword",
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is working as expected, however now I have different requirement, where I'll now have the cityName and cityId as arrays. (the name and id will be mapped with the array index).

Example:

```
cityName: ["New York", "Delhi", "Mumbai"],
cityId: ["150p7", "171x9", "183l0"]
```

How can I now run the same aggregation where I receive the cityNames, and also their Ids using the sub-aggregation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean your input is cityName: ["New York", "Delhi", "Mumbai"], cityId: ["150p7", "171x9", "183l0"] ?

Comment: Hi, @Mathew This: cityName: ["New York", "Delhi", "Mumbai"], cityId: ["150p7", "171x9", "183l0"] is how I'll be storing records now.

Comment: sorry, I don't konw what you mean. Just let me know the array you mentioned is output or input?

Comment: Hey @Mathew This is the Input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it builds a runtime_field to filter cityName and cityId at the same time.

```
    {
        "size": 0,
        "runtime_mappings": {
            "city_and_id": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "script": {
                    "source": "emit(doc['cityName.keyword'].value + '-' +  doc['cityId.keyword'].value)"
                }
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "city_and_id": ["Delhi-171x9"]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "cName": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "cityName.keyword",
                    "size": 1000
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "cId": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "cityId.keyword",
                            "size": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```